# Performance of Oriented Object Programming in C++ on RPi

Tags: c++, performance, oop, raspberry-pi

I'm actually in a project running many Python scripts in a Raspberry Pi. But the CPU capacity is almost full. Hence, I wanna rewrite some scripts in C++ to optimise them a bit.

I suppose there is no difference between C and C++ for performance, as I can create a C-like program in C++. But my question is about OOP. I really like it, but I'm wondering, in the case to have better performance, is it not better to use procedural programming?
I don't know if it makes such a big difference? I guess to access data in memory, it should take longer to check-in attributes. I would have at least to use one object from a lib, but I can avoid creating an object for my own business.
I don't know, for example, if using a char array is really faster than a string?

Also, what about enum, comparing to object or separated variables?

Moreover in my script, I have many threads that are running, so I would have some global variable, does it decrease the performance?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: It's impossible to answer in the general case, well written code will be faster than poorly written code no matter which language or idiom is used. Your c++ code won't necessarily be faster than your python scripts. Have you tried optimising your python scripts?

Comment: Because I'm more comfortable with C++ than Python, that's why I wanna optimising it in C++. (We choose Python first to be fast and because other developers prefer Python). Actually, I always learned than interpreted languages are slower than compiled ones.
But maybe I'm wrong, and hoping too much improvement :/